# AlwaysOn feature does not work correctly when using a rewrite rule to redirect http to https

Tags: spring, tomcat, azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure PaaS instance running a Spring-Boot packaged 'war' inside a Tomcat8 container.  The problem is that, after a period of in-activity, the 'java' process is killed.

[image]

The above image is how it should look like when the tomcat process is not killed.

The tomcat process again starts only when I again make any sort of request to the server.

If my understanding is correct, the flag 'WEBSITE_SCM_ALWAYS_ON_ENABLED' is for the instance to stay alive i.e. the 'w3wp' process and not for Tomcat.

One solution to this problem is to 'poll' my server with a simple 'health' request to keep it alive.

It would be better if there was some Azure configuration or Spring-boot configuration for its 'httpPlatformHandler' so that I can prevent it from going to sleep.

Any help is appreciated.

**** **UPDATE** ****

With further help from @DavidEbbo, the problem was traced to a URL 'rewrite' rule that I had for going from 'http' to 'https' urls.
The 'AlwaysOn' request is on HTTP (Port 80) and thus whenever the Azure request was being hit, it was getting a redirect(301) 
as a response.  Still awaiting a solution.

Comment: very good feedback. I'll send this to the team.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio thank you.  Would love to get an answer back soon.

Comment: I renamed the question to better match the root issue (which is not Java specific, and would also happen for .NET, Node, etc...).

Comment: @DavidEbbo thank you.  I'll try your latest answer and get back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of the problem is that the URL rewrite rule that you are using to redirect http to https is preventing the AlwaysOn warmup requests from reaching your Java app.

Luckily, there is a solution.

### Solution #1: use an XDT transform

Use the following steps:

- Remove the rewrite rule from your web.config
- Instead, use [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) (or FTP but that's harder) to create a file called `applicationHost.xdt` file under your 'site' folder (i.e. `d:\home\site\applicationHost.xdt`). Hint: you can type `touch applicationHost.xdt` in Kudu Console to create an empty file.
- Edit that file and paste the XDT file found [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#redirect-http-traffic-to-https) under the 'Redirect http traffic to https' section.
- Save the file and restart your site from Portal.

Note that the AlwaysOn requests will still look like 301s in the http logs, but the right thing will still happen (i.e. Java will wake up).

### Solution #2: make the change directly in your web.config

Alternatively, if you don't want to use an XDT transform and want to keep everything in your web.config, you can just add the missing pieces there. Specifically, you'll need two changes (matching the XDT above):

Add this condition to your rewrite rule:

```
<add input="{WARMUP_REQUEST}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
```

Add this `applicationInitialization` section under `system.webServer`:

```
<applicationInitialization>
  <add initializationPage="/" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

But I suggest the XDT approach as it doesn't require tricky edits, and keeps those 'messy' things separate from your code base.

### Original answer

The correct way to enable Always On is to set it to On in the Azure portal. `WEBSITE_SCM_ALWAYS_ON_ENABLED` is not something that you can set, but it's something that Azure sets as a result of enabling Always On.

Once you enable Always On, the root of your site (i.e. `/`) will be hit every few minutes, which should keep it alive.

If you need additional paths to be hit, you can use applicationInitialization. More details [here](http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/).

Comment: I did the set option through the portal as you mentioned.  I just put it up there for mentioning the exact name of the flag that gets set.

Comment: The thing that eludes me is the fact that the 'java' goes away on being idle even after this.  I'll take a look at the link you've shared.

Comment: this 'applicationIntialization' module is for an IIS server. Is there a similar module/configuration for Tomcat through which I can specify the path to be hit for a 'health' polling?

Comment: Everything goes through IIS on Azure Web App, so you can use this section even for Tomcat. But this should only be needed if hitting `/` is not good enough to wake up your Java site. You may want to turn on http logging on your Web App to check for those AlwaysOn ping requests. They have a user agent set to "AlwaysOn", so they're easy to recognize.

Comment: In my http logs, I do see the "AlwaysOn" request being logged but it always gets a 301 response back on each line.  Is this the problem? I have the `/` context path mapped to a controller but it wouldn't even get to the actual code since the process is stopped.

Comment: The reason for the '301' redirect is because of a `rewrite` rule that we have for going from 'http' urls to 'https' in our `web.config`.  Since the 'AlwaysOn' request is on HTTP(80), it gets a redirect(301).  Can 'AlwaysOn' be configured to hit HTTPS(443) rather than the HTTP port?

Comment: You should update your question to mention the https redirection, as that is a key part of the issue. It should be solvable and I'll get you the proper way to do this after I test it.

Comment: Ok, I wrote a whole new answer about making things work with the rewrite rule. I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, @DavidEbbo.  We now have the app up and running all the time.  One more rule that we did write before the one that you've mentioned is - `<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^(?!.*AlwaysOn).*$" />`.

Comment: Normally, you should not need this extra line. Did it not work without it? Note that having it there means an external client can send this user agent and end up accessing your app over http. This may or may not be a concern for you, but please be aware of it.

Comment: We have removed the 'user-agent' matcher now as the warmup_request does work.  Thanks again for all your help! :)

Comment: Please be aware that initializationPage, if other specified does not make the AlwaysOn feature to use that url. I had to make an extra rewrite rule for that. Another thing I noticed: `{WARMUP_REQUEST}` did not work for me, did this behavior changed? Is there some official documentation about the WARMUP_REQUEST variable?